# std::make_unique with null pointer?

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr

I have not been able to find any documentation about what happens if I pass a null pointer to `std::make_unique`.

Is an exception thrown?

Comment: What is the underlying reason for the question? Why do you think that there's something unusual or extraordinary in passing null pointer to `make_unique`? How is passing null pointer different from passing, say. `42` or `"Hello World"`?

Comment: `make_unique` does not take a pointer and "make it unique", it creates ("makes") an object that has unique and transferrable ownership. `std::make_unique<int*>(nullptr)` creates a null `int*` with those properties.

Comment: Show the code demonstrating what you're *really* asking about, because frankly the question as/is doesn't make  sense. `std::make_unqiue<Type>` creates a dynamic `Type` instance and assigns ownership to the then-returned `std::unique_ptr<Type>` object. This sounds like you think `std::make_unique` does something else, or your confusing `std::make_unique` with the constructor for `std::unique_ptr`; they're different beasts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[std::make_unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) forwards all the arguments passed to a matching target constructor.
Therefore, if you pass `nullptr`, it will search for a constructor that accepts nullptr_t (or any matching constructor). If it is not there, it will fail to compile.

```
class A
{
public:
   A(void*) { ... } // could also be A(int*) or template <typename T> A(T*)
};

...
std::make_unique<A>(nullptr); // constructs an A by calling A(void*), passing nullptr.
```

Comment: It is not necessary that the constructor had the declaration A( void * ). It can be for example A( int * ); or A( T *ptr, Args ...args );

Answer (score 5):

`std::make_unique` is meant to construct an object wrapped by forwarding the arguments to the constructor of the wrapped object.

Passing `nullptr` to it doesn't make any sense in the way you mean. If you need to clear the content of a `std::unique_ptr` just call `reset()`.